# Google SpeechClient service's authorisation does not recognise the environment variable set.

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I have been trying to use the SpeechClient in one of my applications which is running on a remote debian machine.I have set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with the value of the path to the json key file(echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS prints the value of the path).I have a service account created with an active billing account too.
However when I run the application, it still complains that the environment variable its looking for is not set.

On my local(mac) setup, I got around the problem by downloading and installing the gcloud sdk.Following that, I ran

> gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file [KEY_FILE]

Is installing the sdk necessary always.Should I be doing it again on the debian instance which is a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set environment variable in /etc/environment file.
then, you have to logout/reboot instance to affect variable.
also, you need to confirm with echo command.